# How to handle aborted ajax in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, abort

Is there any method that is called when we call abort before we send ajax request in jquery?

```
$.ajax({
 beforeSend: function(jqxhr, s){
     jqxhr.abort();
 }, 
 complete: function(){
     console.log('complete');
 },
 error: function(){
    console.log('error');
 },
 done: function(){
    console.log('done');
 },
 abort: function(){ // something like this?
    console.log('aborterd');
 }
});
```

None of these are invoked when abort is called.